# Webpack large Bundle Size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I am facing issue due to large webpack bundle size.

The size of my bundle size is nearby 166 kb. I am running webpack with -p flag. Most of the size is due to bundling of react module in my bundle file. So, what I am trying to do is that I am making two bundles: one which contain my app specific code and the other one which contains minified version of the npm which do not change frequently.

My bundle size is now 20 Kb.

Here is my webpack config file :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js'),
    output: getOutput(),
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : "eval",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: /src/,
                loaders: [
                    'style',
                    'css',
                    'autoprefixer?browsers=last 3 versions',
                    'sass?outputStyle=expanded'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'url?limit=8192',
                    'img'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: (node_modules_dir),
                loaders: [
                    'react-hot',
                    'babel-loader?presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015',
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }

};

module.exports = config;

function getOutput() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        return {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        }
    } else {
        return {
            publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my code :

```
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import React  from "react"
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import reducers from "./reducers";
import {increment} from "./actions/App.js";
var store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        ...reducers
    })
);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <span>Value is : {this.props.value}</span>

            <div onClick={this.props.increment}><span>Increment</span></div>
        </div>
    }
}

App = connect((state)=> {
    return {value: state.app.value}
}, {increment})(App);

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: ()=> {
        return <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
    }
});
```

and here is my package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "Sample App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-server": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors --port 3000",
    "serve-web": "npm run webpack-server",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --optimize-minimize"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "http-server": "^0.8.0",
    "img-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "node-fetch": "^1.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.8",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  }
}
```

So, I have changed

```
module.exports = require('./lib/React');
```

to

```
module.exports = window.React;
```

in react.js file of react module as other npm like redux is also using react npm.

Is it a good thing to apply this patch in react.js file of react npm?

Is it a good thing to make two bundles like this?

Comment: 166kb is not large js... if you enable gzip this will  reduce the actual file load size.. gzip can be enable either on web-server side or node server

Comment: This is just a sample. Bundle size of my live web application is near 1.3 MB. I am trying to reduce that.

Comment: you can also use ExtractTextPlugin to pull out the css out of bundle

Comment: Actually, I have not included css in my bundle. I have included them from my index.html file.

Comment: but you are using style loader, which includes the css in bundle as far as i know, also if you dynamically calculating dependencies using json ? then remove move babel, webpack , all loaders and plugins related stuffs to dev-dependencies

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to modify the React library itself. Are you expecting to do this when you deploy to Production? That is, run `npm install` then hand-edit all of your affected dependencies? Just use code splitting - it comes with webpack for this exact purpose: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: @abhirathore2006 Thanks.I was forgetting enabling gzip at the server. Enabling it helped me a lot.

Comment: @lux I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks abhi and lux. Your suggestions helps a lot to us. We were really facing issue due to large bundle size. We have now used compress at server as well as code splitting to make separate bundle for npms. Really Thanks

Comment: @RohitBansal Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use source map explorer to detect what is the problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer